# Inputting JSON file as variable in ModelBuilder using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, modelbuilder, json, geoprocessing-service

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 and trying to create a Geoprocessing service using ModelBuilder, the input of my GP service is in JSON format.

Is it possible to set up the ModelBuilder to accept the JSON input as a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

[Filtering MB parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-filtering-parameter-values.htm)

[File Filter](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-filtering-parameter-values.htm)

In short:

1. Create variable of type `File`
2. Right click > Model as Parameter
3. Open Model properties > Parameters tab
4. Under Filter column, specify the `File` filter type
5. Input `json` or other parameters, semicolon delimited (eg `json; js;`)

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON is a GeoJSON, you can use the JSON to Features Conversion Tools toolbox to import the JSON to a geodatabase format before using as an input for the service.